# How can I highlight the current number in pagination - GridView PagerTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my current design in my GridView, the cells becomes orange on hover, this is achieved by using css. But my problem is how can I changed the cell background color if it is the one that is active?

Image: [Current Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jq4h.png)

HTML Code: (Only GridView)

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
    AllowPaging="True" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound"
    Style="position: static">
    <PagerSettings Position="Top" Mode="Numeric" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Underline="False" CssClass="pager" />
    <PagerTemplate>
        <table id="tablePager">
            <tr style="background-color: #F8F8F8;">
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="First" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="First" runat="server"
                        Text="&lt;&lt; First" Style="color: black" ForeColor="Black" Font-Underline="False"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Previous" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" runat="server"
                        Text="&lt; Previous" Style="color: black" ForeColor="Black" Font-Underline="False"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="Repeater_ItemDataBound" OnLoad="Repeater_Load">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <td id="cell">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPageNumber" CommandName="Page" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Font-Underline="False" />

                        </td>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Next" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" runat="server"
                        Text="Next &gt;" ForeColor="Black" Font-Underline="False"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Last" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Last" runat="server"
                        Text="Last &gt;&gt;" Style="color: black" ForeColor="Black" Font-Underline="False"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </PagerTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

**Page Load**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulateGridView();
    }
}
```

**PopulateGridView**

```
public void PopulateGridView()
{
    String constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconnect"].ToString();
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tabletester"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(reader);

        con.Close();

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Repeater_ItemCommand**

```
protected void Repeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Page")
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridView1.DataBind();
        PopulateGridView();
    }
}
```

**Repeater_ItemDataBound**

```
protected void Repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnkPageNumber = new LinkButton();
    System.Int32 pageNumber = (System.Int32)e.Item.DataItem;

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        lnkPageNumber = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkPageNumber");
        lnkPageNumber.Text = pageNumber.ToString();
        lnkPageNumber.CommandArgument = (pageNumber - 1).ToString();
    }
}
```

**Repeater_Load**

```
protected void Repeater_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater Repeater = (Repeater)sender;
    Repeater.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, GridView1.PageCount);
    Repeater.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this in `Repeater_ItemDataBound`

```
if (e.Item.ItemIndex == GridView1.PageIndex)
{
    lnkPageNumber.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

That said, do you now a GridView has a build-in paging system? Much easier that the overly complex stuff you are doing. Below is all the code it takes:

ASPX

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" 
   OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"></asp:GridView>
```

CODE

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        BindDataToGridView();
    }
}

private void BindDataToGridView()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = source;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindDataToGridView();
}
```

This is IT. All the code you need for a functional paging system.

Comment: I understand, but I have to include first, previous, next, and last button that's why I took this route. and I have to include the page numbers to a table cells for design purposes.

Comment: Then take a look at my answer here, it show some standard pager options and how to customize: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636127/how-to-create-a-show-all-button-in-gridview-pager-or-datapager. But the first pas of my answer should answer your question.